How to allow normal handling of CTRL+C on Windows using PDCurses?
As by the docs, I built PDCurses for Windows 32-bit using MinGW 14.1.0, outputting pdcurses.a. Apparently the mode nocbreak() should let CTRL+C be handled as a signal, closing the program, so I wrote the following program.
#include "curses.h"

int main()
{
        initscr();

        /* PDcusres starts on 'cbreak' mode. */
        noraw();
        nocbreak();

        getch();
        getch();

        endwin();
        return 0;
}

I compiled it, and tried it on CMD, PowerShell and Tabby. When I pressed CTRL+C, "^C" was written on screen and nothing happened, it seemed to be treated as a character. The program was not closed.
So how can I let PDCurses know to let such commands be handled normally?

just calling noraw() should be enough to make ctrl-C work properly (exit the process) in PDCurses on a windows console.  Note that if you're NOT using a console (using some other window that has been created), the ctrl-C may not do anything special.

@ChrisDodd, does it work normally on your Windows?

Looking at the latest code, it looks like it is unconditionally using SetConsoleCtrlHandler to ignore ctrl-C, which seems odd.  You might try calling SetConsoleCtrlHandler(NULL, FALSE); to restore normal ctrl-C/ctrl-break handling -- see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/ctrl-c-and-ctrl-break-signals

Actually, reading more carefully, it is leaving the ignore/exit for ctrl-C unchanged from whatever the parent process specified.  It will catch ctrl-C to exit windowing mode, but will then let the default handler handle it.  So calling SetConsoleCtrlHandler(NULL, FALSE); should set the defaul handler to to exit.  Alternately, there is likely some setting in your preferences that is defaulting to ignoring ctrl-C somewhere.

@ChrisDodd, thank you a lot! You could write an answer if that really works. The weird thing is that CTRL-C works on other programs, like gdb, net, and normal console programs I write.
